# Replicate base::data.frame behavior with dplyr::tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

I want to create a vector of names from objects found in the environment, and have that vector in a `tibble`. It works when you use a `base::data.frame()`, as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

# three objects in the environment

str_c("x", 1:3) %>% 
  map(
    ~assign(., "", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  )

data.frame(
  v1 = ls()
  )
```

this returns

```
  v1
1 x1
2 x2
3 x3
```

but if I try to use `dplyr::tibble()`, I get

```
tibble(
  v1 = ls()
)

# A tibble: 1 x 1
  v1   
  <chr>
1 ~
```

How can I have `tibble` replicate the `data.frame` behavior?

Comment: I don't want to be judgmental, but is there a reason you would want to do this?

Comment: sheer perversity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enframe` from `tibble`, updated to remove the superfluous name vector:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# three objects in the environment

str_c("x", 1:3) %>% 
  map(
    ~assign(., "", envir = .GlobalEnv)
  )
#> [[1]]
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] ""
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] ""

enframe(ls(), value = "v1", name = NULL)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 1
#>   v1   
#>   <chr>
#> 1 x1   
#> 2 x2   
#> 3 x3
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: close, but provides a superfluous `name` vector

Comment: @tomw Amended answer to remove the name vector.